# How to get Event bus metrics Vertx integrate with Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, vert.x, micrometer

I'm using VertX Metrics build-in with Prometheus.
Here my code setup:

```
try {
        MicrometerMetricsOptions options = new MicrometerMetricsOptions()
        .setPrometheusOptions(new VertxPrometheusOptions().setEnabled(true))
        .setEnabled(true);
        
        Vertx vert = Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions().setMetricsOptions(options));
        
        vert.deployVerticle(ExecBlocking.class, new DeploymentOptions());
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
```

But when I run vertx instance on localhost:8080, I can not find **Event Bus Metric, HTTP Client Metric, Net Client Metric..** (these metrics can not seen on **GET** localhost:8080/metrics , just see **HTTP Server Metric** and **Vert.x pool metrics**

[image: metrics vertx search on prometheus]

**My question:**
How to see missing metric (Event bus, Net, HTTP Client) on **GET** localhost:8080/metrics

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that:

The metrics (Event bus,...) just only display on GET if there is event about these metrics happened.

So I did testing send message into event bus, then I can view metrics related to Event bus on GET metric request.

I deployed a verticle to send message into event bus:

```
public class EventBusProducer extends AbstractVerticle {
@Override
public void start() throws Exception {
vertx.setPeriodic(1000, x -> {
  Greetings.get(vertx, greetingResult -> vertx.eventBus().send("greeting", greetingResult.result()));
   });
  }
}

class Greetings {
   private static final String[] GREETINGS = {
      "Hello world!",
      "Bonjour monde!",
      "Hallo Welt!",
      "Hola Mundo!"
   };
   private static final Random RND = new Random();

   private Greetings() {
   }

   static void get(Vertx vertx, Handler<AsyncResult<String>> responseHandler) {
     vertx.executeBlocking(fut -> {
     // Simulate worker pool processing time between 200ms and 2s
     int processingTime = RND.nextInt(1800) + 200;
     try {
        Thread.sleep(processingTime);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    fut.complete(GREETINGS[RND.nextInt(4)]);
  }, responseHandler);
 }
}
```